# Como setar um jcombobox em um PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, swing

Como eu faço um jcombobox nesse método? O Combobox seria no tipo que o usuário é suposto a escolher, eu tentei fazer um mas não deu muito certo. E esse método está na minha classe principal e como eu faço para setar em um *PreparedStatement* que está em uma classe Dao?

### Meu método que está na classe Main

```
 public static void inserirEnderecoTeste(){
        Bean viagem = new Bean();

        Object[] opcoes = {"Um","Dois","Tres","Quatro"};  
        viagem.setTipo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escolha um item" , "Selecao de itens" ,  
         JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE , null ,opcoes,""));


        viagem.setDataInicio(DataHelper.StringToCalendar("dd/MM/yyyy", 
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a data de inicio:\n(Deve ser no formato  DD/MM/YYYY)", "30/05/2015")));
        viagem.setDataFim(DataHelper.StringToCalendar("dd/MM/yyyy", 
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a data de fim:\n(Deve ser no formato  DD/MM/YYYY)", "01/05/2015")));
        viagem.setCidade(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a cidade:"));
        viagem.setUf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o bairro:"));
        viagem.setValorDiaria(new Double(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Valor da diária:")));
        viagem.setColaborador(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira um colaborador"));
        viagem.setCliente(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira um cliente"));
        //vb.setCidade(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira a cidade Destino:", "Angra dos Reis"));



        if (Dao.inserir(viagem)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inseriu!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não Inseriu!");
        }
    }
 }
```

### Essa é a classe `Dao` onde eu supostamente tenho que setar o *jcombobox*

```
public static boolean inserir(Bean endereco) {
        boolean executou = false;
        if (ConexaoMySQL.conectar()) {
            try {
                Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getConexao();
                String sql = "Insert into viagem values (0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        >>>>>>>     pstm.setString(1,endereco.getTipo()); <<<<<<<<<<<
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente, o seguinte funciona (apesar de a pergunta aparecer no título):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual é o seu nome?"));
    JComboBox<String> options = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {
            "Desenvolvedor", "Colaborador", "Visitante"
    });
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, options, "Qual é o seu título?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println(options.getSelectedItem());
}
```

O segredo foi usar [JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (veja a documentação aqui)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)).

Também vale a pena dar uma olhada nesta [resposta no StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522854/1064325).

---

*Edição:*

Em seu `Bean`, deixe o atributo `tipo` como `String`, ao invés de `JComboBox`.

Comment: Cara eu fiz desse jeito:                                                                              Object[] opcoes = {"Um","Dois","Tres","Quatro"};  
  viagem.setTipo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escolha um item" , "Selecao de itens" ,  
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE , null ,opcoes,""));
  O meu problema está em como eu vou setar isso no meu preparestatemente:                                                                                              >>>>>>>     pstm.setString(1,endereco.getTipo()); <<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: @Jarwin Qual o problema com `endereco.getTipo()`?

Comment: Eu só não sei como retornar isso no pstm.setString();

Comment: Por exemplo para cidade eu faço assim:pstm.setString(4,endereco.getCidade());

Comment: Eu vou atualizar a classe Main da pergunta para você ver como eu estou criando o meu Jcombobox blz?

Comment: Ué, mas o `pstm.setString(1, endereco.getTipo())` deveria funcionar, uma vez que você está setando o atributo `tipo` do `Bean` via `viagem.setTipo(...)`. Qual o problema? Não está compilando? Está dando algum erro? Não está salvando com o valor certo?

Comment: Tirei um print do erro tá na pergunta diz que setString(int, String) no preparestatement não é aplicado para os argumentos(in,JcomboBox)

Comment: Aaaaa é porque não é mais string no meu Bean e sim um object por isso que tá dando isso mas aogra eu troquei para pstm.setObject(1,endereco.getTipo()); e tá dando outro erro                                     '-'

Comment: Apenas deixe como `String` no `Bean`, e tudo irá resolver: tanto o `viagem.setTipo(...)` quanto o `pstm.setString(1, endereco.getTipo())`!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25335/discussion-between-jarwin-and-falsarella).